# Where to place external DLL in C#?

Tags: c#, dll, unmanaged

If I reference an external unmanaged DLL in C# by the following:

```
[DLLImport("MyDLL.dll",  ...
```

Where should the DLL be placed when I want to run the code from my IDE?  Should it be in the `bin\Debug` folder?

Answer (score 1):

Which compiling configuration you are using?

If you want to run the application from Visual Studio Debug/Run it would be in your project folder

If you want to run by double click, it should be near your exe which is in

bin\Debug

or

bin\Release

folder.

Comment: Actually, the directory where the executable file exists is searched before the working directory, and in secure configurations, the working directory is never searched.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx

Comment: But the second location, the one with the .exe, also works, and it's a better option because Windows looks there first.

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere locatable by the [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx) function. See [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx) for more information:

> If `SafeDllSearchMode` is enabled, the search order is as follows:
>
> - The directory from which the application loaded.
> - The system directory. Use the `GetSystemDirectory` function to get the path of this directory.
> - The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
> - The Windows directory. Use the `GetWindowsDirectory` function to get the path of this directory.
> - The current directory.
> - The directories that are listed in the `PATH` environment variable. Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by the App Paths registry key. The App Paths key is not used when computing the DLL search path.

`bin\Debug` satisfies the first point, assuming that you're only ever running the application in its `Debug` configuration.

Comment: I would emphasize that the first option is actually the _best_ one. For security reasons, as well as for deployment and maintenance reasons (at least as long as the native DLL is yours as well and doesn't come with a separate installer). If you need to run in "Release" configuration, you can also put it in bin\Release.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, alongside the `.exe` file produced by the compiler (which ends up in `bin\Debug\` as you said) should be perfect.